# Compressing with BarCat?

Tags: linux, compression, tar

I'm having an issue using Barcat to show a dialog while compressing? Wondering what the exact syntax is?

here's a link to [Barcat](http://www.theiling.de/projects/bar.html)

things I've tried are

```
  bar -n apache24.tar.xz |tar -Jcf -
  bar -n apache24.tar.xz |tar -Jcf - apache24/
  bar -n apache24.tar.xz |tar -Jcf apache24/ - 
  bar -c 'tar -Jcf apache24/ apache.tar.xz'
  bar -c 'tar -Jcf apache.tar.xz apache24/'
  bar -n apache24.tar.xz apache24/ |tar -Jcf - 
  bar -n apache24/ apache24.tar.xz |tar -Jcf - 
  bar -n apache24/ |tar -Jcf - 
  bar -n apache24/ |tar -Jcf -- apache.tar.xz
  bar -n apache.tar.xz  |tar -Jcf apache24/ --
  bar -n apache.tar.xz -- apache24/ |tar -Jcf -
  bar -n apache.tar.xz apache24/ |tar -Jcf -
  bar -n apache.tar.xz apache24/ |tar -Jcf --
  bar -n apache24/ apache.tar.xz |tar -Jcf -
```

Excuse any dupes I just pasted from history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't do that, at least not as conveniently as you'd probably like. To understand why, you have to consider how such a program would work. In the decompression case, it can easily stat the original `.tar.xz` file to get its size, and the progress can be computed as the number of bytes that have passed through `bar`, divided by the file size. But in the compression case, `bar` isn't smart enough to figure out the original size of the directory, nor does it know the ultimate size of an input that's piped to it (e.g., if the output of `tar` is streamed to `bar`).

`bar` seems to accept a `-s` option so that you can help it out with the expected size, but I couldn't get it to actually produce a correct output. That looks something like this, if you want to play around with it more:

```
tar cf - apache24/ | bar -s $(du -sb apache24 | cut -f1) | xz > apache24.tar.xz
```

In practice, you'd probably have to add a fudge factor to the `du` output to account for the overheads in the `tar` format. Obviously, not very convenient to have to do.